# Having trouble selecting sub menu item

Tags: html, css, menu

I am having a hard time trying to hover over the 3rd sub menu link from the 3rd menu link.

If you hover over the 3rd link you get a sub menu. From there there is another inner sub menu that opens after hovering over the 2nd sub menu link. However when I try to go down and hover over the 3rd sub menu link the dropdown goes away and it becomes hard to hover over that 3rd link.

```css
*,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  background-color: white;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  box-shadow: 4px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.header-bot-links{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 460px;

  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;

  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.link{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 9px;
  transition: .5s color,
    .5s background-color;
}
.link:nth-child(2){
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.link:nth-child(2),
.link:nth-child(3),
.link:nth-child(4){
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.link:hover{
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.glyphicon{
  position: absolute;
  top:13px;
}
.glyphicon-menu-left{
  left: 20px;
}
.glyphicon-menu-right{
  right: 20px;
}
.sub-menu,
.in-sub-menu{
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 1s all;
}
.link3:hover .sub-menu{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.sub-menu-item{
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  transition: 1s all;
}
.sub-menu-item:hover{
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.sub-menu-item:nth-child(1){
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.sub-menu-item:nth-child(3){
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
}
.sub2:hover{
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.sub2:hover .in-sub-menu{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.in-sub-menu-item{
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  transition: 1s all;
}
.in-sub-menu-item:hover{
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header-bot-links">
   <a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>Link 1
   </a>
   <a href="#out" class="link">
    Link 2
   </a>
   <a href="#rest" class="link link3">
    Link 3

    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li class="sub-menu-item">Sub Menu Item 1</li>

     <li class="sub-menu-item sub2">Sub Menu Item 2
      <ul class="in-sub-menu">
       <li class="in-sub-menu-item">TEST </li>
       <li class="in-sub-menu-item">TEST 2</li>
       <li class="in-sub-menu-item">TEST 3</li>
      </ul>
     </li>

     <li class="sub-menu-item">Sub Menu Item 3</li>
    </ul>
   </a>
   <a href="#night" class="link">
    Link 4
   </a>
   <a href="#" class="link">
    Link 5<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right">
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[Codepen demo.](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/QKQbqZ)

Comment: I don't really understand your question, I was able to hover over the third link just fine, although it took me a few tries. I had to scroll down to reach it, and often times my mouse would leave the parent and close the menu. You may want to consider opening the second submenu to the right like a traditional dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your nav menu is at the bottom of your codepen demo, and the dropdowns are not currently visible. Please update your codepen demo to be at the top, or have the sub menu items appear above bar.

Comment: The core issue with this menu is that the sub menu items are stacked vertically. It is generally considered best practice to have each sub menu appear to the right of its parent item.

You can find an example of this here:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3